# Using a class in a Foreach (MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, class, foreach

I have a tad of a problem! In my MVC it is giving me the "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object." problem whenever it tries to run the MVC.

Basically, this is the code in the controller:

```
 public PartialViewResult ViewAllFaults()
{
     List<AdminLogEntries> faults = new FaultService.FaultServiceClient().GetAllOfFaultDetails().ToList();            
     ViewBag.ListOfFaults = faults;
     return PartialView("_viewallfaults", faults);
}
```

This is the code in my view:

```
@foreach (Common.Views.AdminLogEntries item in ViewBag.ListOfFaults)
{
<tr>
    <td>
        @item.FaultID
    </td>
{...}
```

And this is my class:

```
namespace Common.Views
{
public class AdminLogEntries
{
    public string FaultID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public DateTime LogDate { get; set; }
    public int OrderID { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
 }
}
```

I read a bit about the IEnumerable but couldn't really implement it or understand it. Thanks for any sort of help!

## **UPDATE:**

So I found out that it wasn't even passing through the controller method! I must be addressing the partial in the wrong way. This is what I wrote in the main view:

```
 @Html.Partial("~/Views/Admin/_viewallfaults.cshtml");
```

That is what is stopping it from accessing the controller I think..

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your code to:

```
@foreach (Common.Views.AdminLogEntries item in Model)
```

as you're passing the faults to the view as its view model in the second parameter:

```
return PartialView("_viewallfaults", faults);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure a ViewBag is available for a partial view... Whatever, you currently use `return PartialView("_viewallfaults", faults);`, then you just have to iterate over your model!

```
@model List<Common.Views.AdminLogEntries>
...
@foreach (Common.Views.AdminLogEntries item in Model)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At a glance there is a number of places where a reference can be null. For the time being, add some null checks and see where it might be. If you add a callstack it might be helpful.

```
FaultService.FaultServiceClient().GetAllOfFaultDetails().ToList();
```

Is GetAllOfFaultDetails() null?

Do the AdminLogEntries items have null IDs?